# Por que processar uma lista ordenada é mais rápido que uma não ordenada?

Tags: otimização, desempenho

Tenho um código em C++ que, por algum motivo inexplicável parece ser executado muito mais rapidamente quando os meus dados estão previamente ordenados. Consegui reproduzir o comportamento com o seguinte código:

```c++
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#define LENGTH 20000000 // 80 MB

unsigned process(int* array) {
    unsigned r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
        if (array[i] < 500)
            r += array[i];
    return r;
}

int main() {
    int* array1 = new int[LENGTH];
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i)
        array1[i] = std::rand() % 1000;

    int* array2 = new int[LENGTH];
    std::memcpy(array2, array1, LENGTH * sizeof(int));
    std::sort(array2, array2 + LENGTH);

    std::clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) process(array1);
    double time1 = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i) process(array2);
    double time2 = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cout << "array1\t" << time1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "array2\t" << time2 << std::endl;
}
```

Tenho o seguinte resultado (compilado com o **g++ 4.8.1**, sem otimizações):

```
array1  22.86
array2  8.557
```

Um aumento de velocidade de quase **3 vezes**! Inicialmente suspeitei que fosse algum tipo de otimização que o compilador pudesse estar fazendo com o meu código, se aproveitando de alguma forma do fato de minha lista estar ordenada. Então decidi implementar a mesma ideia em uma linguagem completamente diferente e que não fosse otimizavél: escolhi o Ruby.

```ruby
require 'benchmark'

array1 = []
20000000.times { array1 << rand(1000) }
array2 = array1.sort

Benchmark.bm do |x|
    x.report("array1") do
        r = 0
        array1.each {|e| r += e if e < 500 }
    end
    x.report("array2") do
        r = 0
        array2.each {|e| r += e if e < 500 }
    end
end
```

O resultado rodando com o **Ruby 2.0.0** (executando 200 vezes a menos por ser mais lento):

```
             user     system      total        real
array1  13.151000   0.000000  13.151000 ( 13.144685)
array2   8.299000   0.000000   8.299000 (  8.293171)
```

Aqui o ganho de perfomance é bastante menor (pouco mais de **1.5x**), mas claramente significativo.

O que exatamente está acontecendo aqui? De onde vem esse efeito e como eu posso me aproveitar dele?

---

<sup>[Baseado em uma pergunta famosa do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array)</sup>

Comment: Bota famosa nisso. É simplesmente a pergunta com mais votos do SO.

Comment: Tentei não simplismente traduzir, mas reescrever do meu jeito. Adoro essa pergunta.

Comment: A ideia do stackoverflow em português é copiar perguntas do inglês pra ganhar reputação?

Comment: @McLeary Não estou tentando ganhar reputação, apenas acho que a pergunta é relevante e trará visibilidade ao site. E a quantidade de perguntas "traduzidas" deve ser sempre insignificativa no fluxo de perguntas reais. Não vejo problema.

Comment: @McLeary Isso já foi debatido na comunidade e trazer informações altamente relevantes para cá, dando o devido crédito é incentivado. Não é para trazer o SO inteiro, mas o que é muito legal que não exista em português é oficialmente incentivado.

Comment: Algumas pessoas trazem perguntas irrelevantes. Elas simplesmente não ganham votos. Mas há casos, como este, que realmente merecem o voto, afinal não é tão *fácil* trazer uma questão como essa. E o trabalho de traduzi-la? Além do mais, pelo que já observei desde o beta privado, o  Guilherme sabe do que está falando e não precisa disso para ganhar pontos.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Você é uma vítima do **preditor de branches**.

## O que é a predição de branches?

Considere uma entroncamento ferroviário:

[image]
<sup>[Imagem por Mecanismo, da Wikimedia Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Entroncamento_do_Transpraia.JPG)</sup>

Agora, para o meu argumento fazer algum sentido suponha que estamos no século XVIII, antes da invenção do rádio e de outros meios de comunicação.

Você é o operador do entroncamento e você nota que há um trem vindo. Você não faz ideia de para qual lado ele pretende ir e qual é o seu destino. Você então faz o trem parar, pergunta do maquinista o destino, ajusta a alavanca e libera o trem para partir.

O problema desde método é que o trem é um monstro pesadíssimo cheio de inercia e parar/partir é um processo que pode levar minutos.

Existe uma forma melhor? Sim! Chute para onde o trem vai sem perguntar.

- Se você acertar o trem vai continuar em frente e todos saem ganhando.
- Mas se você errar o trem precisará parar, regridir e partir.

**Se você acertar sempre** o trem nunca precisará parar.
**Se você errar muito frequentemente** o trem perderá tempo parando e regredindo. Mas isso é quase tão ruim quanto parar para perguntar.

---

Admito que a analogia pode não ser tão boa, afinal o trem poderia sinalizar a direção com uma bandeira ou algo do tipo. Mas em computadores não há como saber que direção o seu código tomará até o momento que a execução chegar até ele. Este é o preditor de branches.

Mas antes de mais nada, **o que é uma branch?**

Considere essa condicional, uma branch:

[image]

Para decidir se `r += array[i]` será ou não executado deve-se primeiro ler o valor de `array[i]` e verificar se ele é menor que `500`. O problema aqui é que processadores modernos podem executar multiplas instruções ao mesmo tempo desde que não haja dependencias entre elas. Para isso funcionar direito ele precisa saber quais são as próximas instruções, e esperar até que a condicional tenha se resolvido é subutilizar o poder computacional.

Mas processadores modernos são melhores que isso. Eles cegamente chutam e tomam um caminho antes do cálculo estar pronto. Quando a condicional estiver pronta se verifica:

- Se o chute foi certeiro, apenas continuar a executar.
- Se o chute estava errado, deve-se parar tudo que está sendo feito, desfazer o que foi executado erroneamente e continuar do ponto logo depois da condicional;

**Se ele acertar sempre** a execução nunca precisará parar.
**Se ele errar muito frequentemente** a execução perderá tempo parando e regredindo. Mas isso é quase tão ruim quanto parar para esperar a decisão.

---

O que os processadores fazem aqui é tentar identificar um padrão e seguir ele para aumentar as chances de obter um chute certeiro. O operador do entroncamento pode notar, por exemplo, que de manhã a maioria dos trens estão indo para um lado, enquanto que trens pintados de vermelho costumam seguir pelo outro caminho.

Quando sua lista não está ordenada a distribuição de valores será proximadamente randomica e uniforme. Sendo assim o resultado de `array[i] < 500` é totalmente imprevisível. Isso resultará em cerca de 50% de erro no preditor.

Mas se sua lista está ordenada, acontecerá que para os primeiros valores de `i` o resultado será sempre `true` já que todos esses valores são baixos. O preditor aprenderá que a condição é sempre verdade e constante. No momento em que a execução passar de metade da array, o resultado começará a ser `false` e o preditor vai errar por alguns ciclos até notar a mudança e passar a assumir que será sempre falso. Isso dá uma taxa de acerto quase total.

O truque é fazer com que todos os branches dentro de seções críticas sejam facilmente previsíveis, podendo lhe proporcionar bastante ganho de performance, mesmo ao custo de previamente ordenar seus dados.

---

Embora eu não indique escrever código assim a menos que seja realmente **necessário**, você pode escapar de depender do preditor escrevendo o mesmo código sem branch alguma:

```c++
if (array[i] < 500)
    r += array[i];
```

```c++
int flag = (array[i] - 500) >> 31; // right shift em valores signed não é portável
r += flag & array[i]; // Se a flag for zero, some zero
```

Não há condicionais envolvidas aqui, apenas manipulações de bits. O primeiro problema é que o comportamento desse código não é imediatamente óbvil para quem o lê, diferente do original. O segundo, e talvez mais importante, é que isso só funciona se o *right shift* for implementado como um [*arithmetic shift*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), que implica que o sinal será preservado e fará toda a palavra ser `1`s.

Testando com o GCC 4.8.1, sem otimização:

- Randomico, com branch: **22.82s**
- Ordenado, com branch: **8.483s**
- Randomico, sem branch: **9.474s**
- Ordenado, sem branch: **9.448s**

Note que embora a ordem não faça mais nenhuma diferença, o resultado é mais lento do que quando o preditor estava em ação e acertando, pois temos mais operações para executar.

---

**Mas e se ligarmos as otimizações?**

Então os números do seu teste mudam um pouco:

- Randomico, com branch: **3.249s**
- Ordenado, com branch: **3.242s**
- Randomico, sem branch: **2.565s**
- Ordenado, sem branch: **2.569s**

Aqui o GCC é esperto o bastante para transformar a branch em um **conditional move**:

```
mov       ecx, DWORD PTR [esi+edx*4]  ; a = array[i]
cmp       ecx, 499                    ; c = a <= 499
lea       ebx, [ecx+eax]              ; t = r + a
cmovle    eax, ebx                    ; if (c) r = t
```

A mágica aqui é que a última instrução **não** é um branch, é executada como apenas uma instrução e não impede o processador de começar a executar as instruções que vem em seguida, não há saltos para outras partes do código, é tudo linear.

Ainda assim ele não foi bom o bastante para superar nosso *hack* com operações de bits, que fica assim:

```
mov       ebx, DWORD PTR [esi+edx*4]  ; a = array[i]
lea       ecx, [ebx-500]              ; b = a - 500
sar       ecx, 31                     ; b = b << 31
and       ecx, ebx                    ; b = b & a
add       eax, ecx                    ; r += b
```

Embora possua mais instruções, é executado mais rapidamente nos meus testes.

---

Você pode também ajudar o compilador e o preditor dizendo no código o resultado provável de uma branch. O código é diferente para cada compilador, mas no GCC você pode escrever o seguinte:

```
#define likely(x)      __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
#define unlikely(x)    __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)

if (likely(array[i] < 950))
    r += array[i];
```

É uma técnica amplamente utilizada no kernel do linux. Mas é preciso testar para saber se será realmente mais rápido que deixar a cargo do preditor no seu cado específico. Pode também contribuir para otimizações por parte do compilador.

---

Vale ressaltar que todos os testes aqui podem e vão variar de processador para processador. Resultados que são melhores no meu podem não ser melhores no seu. Para a maioria dos casos o melhor é escrever código simples e legível e deixar para o compilador a tarefa de decidir como o executar.

---

<sup>[Baseado em uma resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902#11227902)</sup>

Comment: Não acredito que você trouxe este post, achava ele fundamental! Pena que esses dias o pessoal não está votando com a mesma vontade que votavam durante o private.