# Melhor prática para criação de if

Tags: c#, desempenho, if

Qual das duas opções de código tem uma performance melhor?

Vou exibir um exemplo bem simples, geralmente há mais código dentro do `if`.

A)

```
string mensagem = "OI";
if(exibirAdeus)
   mensagem = "Adeus";
```

B)

```
string mensagem = "";
if(exibirAdeus)
  mensagem = "Adeus";
else 
  mensagem = "OI";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pergunta é pertinente sim caso o bloco de código no if contenha alta complexidade computacional, escritas no banco de dados ou em arquivos, etc..

O ideal, entre os dois, seria o (A).

### Porque Performance(A) >= Performance(B)

**Caso 1**: a execução do programa tenha sempre `exibirAdeus = true`, **Performance(A) = Performance(B)**. Tanto (A) como (B), acabarão sempre tendo o mesmo fluxo:

Algoritmo (A), Algoritmo (B):

```
1. Atribui "" ou "Oi" para `message`
2. Verifica `exibirAdeus == true`
3. Atribui "Adeus" para `message`
```

**Caso 2**: a execução do programa tenha 1 ou mais `exibirAdeus = false`, **Performance(A) > Performance(B)**. Porque para esses casos (B) será mais custoso:

Algoritmo (A):

```
1. Atribui "Oi" para `message`
2. Verifica `exibirAdeus == true`: falso, não faz nada (message já é "Oi"). continua adiante.
```

Algoritmo (B):

```
1. Atribui "" para `message`
2. Verifica `exibirAdeus == true`: falso, precisa atribuir "Oi".
3. Atribui "Oi" para `message`
```

### Mundo Real

No entanto, caso esse bloco seja pequeno e de baixa complexidade, isso se torna extremamante desnecessário.

O caminho que tu iria seguir é: O quão esse código está legível e fácil de dar manutenção (legibilidade & manutenabilidade). Digo isso porque há um consenso* que nesse caso apresentado, deverias se preocupar mais em colocar as chaves ({}) para demarcar os blocos do if-else.

```
string mensagem = "OI";     // padrão: caso mais provável...
if (exibirAdeus) {
   mensagem = "Adeus";
}
```

ou ainda, caso o código comece a ficar mais complicado como lembrado por C. E. Gesser:

```
private bool Teste(){
    [..]
    string mensagem = initMensagem(condicao);
    [..]
}

private string initMensagem(bool condicao){
    if (condicao) {
      return "Adeus";
    }
    return "OI";
}
```

### Outro caso comum

```
string message = "";
if (condicao == 1){
   message = "blablbla";
}
else if (condicao == 2){
   message = "Lorem";
}
else if (condicao == 3){
   message = "Ipsum";
}
[..]
else {
   message = "Dolor";
}
```

Seria melhor escrito assim** por performance, legibilidade e manutenabilidade:

```
string message = "";
switch (condicao) {
    case 1: 
       message = "blablbla";
       break;
    case 2: 
       message = "Lorem";
       break;
    case 3: 
       message = "Ipsum";
       break;
    [..]
    default: 
       message = "Dolor";
}
```

---

*
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16528
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2715
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786949

**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395618

Comment: Para casos mais complicados, a organização do código fica melhor refatorando a lógica de inicialização para uma outra função:

    `string message = initMessage(condicao);`

Comment: Concordo! Melhor ainda!

Comment: @AndréFigueiredo porque e' que Porque Performance(A) >= Performance(B)?

Comment: "=" porque caso `exibirAdeus==true` em todos os casos durante a execução, o else nunca será executado; o fluxo será sempre o mesmo para ambos os casos: sempre ser criada a variável, inicializada, verificado `exibirAdeus==true`, e a variável atualizada para "Adeus".
">" para outros casos onde haverá algum `exibirAdeus==false` , onde (B) irá denegrir a performance pelo custo de atualizar a variável - a medida que ocorram mais `exibirAdeus==false`, (A) não irá atualizar.

Comment: O fluxo nao tem custo. O que custa e' a criaccao de objectos. E no caso A, se `exibirAdeus==false`, 2 objectos sao criados: "OI" e "Adeus" - e o objecto "OI" foi criado desnecessariamente. O caso ideal seria o caso C, como demonstrado na minha resposta.

Comment: Fique curioso do porquê usar `case` é menos custoso que vários laços `if\else`.

Comment: @felipe.avelar `switch` e' mais eficiente que `if/else` se houverem 5 ou mais casos. Se houverem >=5 casos, o `switch` e' implementado usando uma *hash table*/*lookup table* - e todos os casos terao acesso constante O(1). No caso demonstrado pelo @AndréFigueiredo, if/else teria melhor performance.

Comment: @felipe.avelar, basicamente é o que @dcastro disse. A explicação detalhada está nos links** no SO em inglês.
Por isso, para identificar que os blocos `if/else` e `switch` são largos, coloquei um `[..]`.

Comment: @dcastro atualizei a resposta com o porquê acredito que  Performance(A) >= Performance(B)

Comment: Na verdade, o passo **1. Cria string `message`** não exite em tempo de execução.

Comment: Bem lembrado @PauloMorgado, atualizei a resposta corretamente

Answer (score 7):

Não sei se vale a pena pensar em performance de um fragmento tão curto e de execução tão rápida. Porém podemos fazer a seguinte análise:

Em A) você inicializa a variável e ela só irá ser atualizada caso a expressão `exibirAdeus` seja verdadeira. Em B) você inicializa a variável com um valor que nunca será utilizado, desta forma terá o custo de atualizar a variável independente do valor de `exibirAdeus`.

Desta forma eu te digo que A) tem melhor performance que B). Mas não por ser C#, mas sim pelo algoritmo utilizado.

Comment: A) não necessariamente tem melhor performance que B). O correto seria performance igual ou melhor.

Comment: Fiquei curioso em saber porque houve um voto negativo aqui. Queria aprender onde está o problema da resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Vale mencionar mais uma opção que escapou nos exemplos apresentados.  Aqui usando o operador ternário.

```
string mensagem = exibirAdeus ? "Adeus" : "OI";
```

Answer (score 3):

O melhor caso não é `A` nem `B`. É `C`:

```
string mensagem;
if(exibirAdeus)
  mensagem = "Adeus";
else 
  mensagem = "OI";
```

Em `A`:

- se exibirAdeus == true, 2 objectos são criados ("OI" e "Adeus")
- se exibirAdeus == false, 1 objecto foi criado ("Oi")

Em `B`:

- se exibirAdeus == true, 2 objectos são criados ("" e "Adeus")
- se exibirAdeus == false, 2 objecto são criados ("" e "Oi")

Em `C`:

- se exibirAdeus == true, 1 objecto foi criado ("Adeus")
- se exibirAdeus == false, 1 objecto foi criado ("Oi")

Answer (score 2):

Levando em conta o seu algoritmo, para o processador a diferença é quase insignificante (como quase todo mundo disse) porem é obvio que se esse `if` estiver dentro de um loop para bilhoes essa diferença minina se torna mais sensivel. Creio que vale a pena você pensar sobre a semantica do que está escrevendo e ver se faz mais sentido o primeiro ou o segundo, melhorando assim a legibilidade e o entendimento.

Answer (score 2):

Como o @Lizard corretamente mencionou, o desempenho depende da probabilidade da condição e também da otimização que o processador é capaz de fazer. Porém, eu acrescentaria aqui a frequência de uso dessa rotina.

Veja [esta interessantíssima questão sobre velocidade de processamento em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3163/por-que-processar-uma-lista-ordenada-e-mais-rapido-que-uma-nao-ordenada). Os processadores modernos são capazes de processar várias instruções por ciclo, então se o resultado da expressão booleana for quase sempre o mesmo, o processador tem a capacidade de "prever" o resultado e otimizar o processamento como se o `if` não existisse.

Eu não sei quão é avançado é o compilador de C#, mas se até numa linguagem de altíssimo nível como Ruby houve ganho de desempenho por otimizações que dependem do processador, então C# não seria uma exceção.

Além disso, se uma rotina assim for usada frequentemente, a String inicial já estará carregada em *cache* e o custo de apontar uma variável para ela será bem pequeno. MNo segundo exemplo, você está apontando para uma String vazia, o que já exige o processamento de atribuição de variável.

Enfim, comparando com os gargalos comuns de desempenho, a diferença desses trechos é praticamente nula. E isso pode ser aplicado para a maioria das linguagens.

Por outro lado, é importante ressaltar que se, além da atribuição, houver qualquer tipo de processamento sobre o objeto o cenário pode mudar drasticamente. Após tantas afirmações de que "não faz diferença", alguém poderia optar pela alternativa A e acrescentar ali uma conversão para *upper case*, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Dentre **A** e **B**, o mais eficiente seria **A**. Mas o melhor mesmo seria um terceiro, um **C**:

```
string mensagem;
if(condicao)
  mensagem = "Adeus";
else
  mensagem = "OI";
```

Mas a eficiência do algoritmo gira em torno da condição que ele for usado, de probabilidade, então, consideramos o pior caso. Em **A** seria ter que mudar `"OI"` para `"Adeus"` depois de verificar a condição, e em **B** seria mudar o `""` para `"OI"` ou `"Adeus"` depois de verificar a condição, tanto faz.
Agora deve vir a pergunta, por quê **C** se ela se parece tanto com **B**, que é pior que **A**? Porque a atribuição em **B** `string mensagem = ""` gera uma atribuição a mais independente do caso. Em **A** a chance de ocorrer uma mudança no valor é de 50%, e em **C** a chance de haver uma mudança não existe, sempre haverá uma atribuição apenas.

De fato o algoritmo é muito simples para considerar sua eficiência, mas dentro de um looping, ou dois, sendo executados milhares de vezes, com diversas possibilidades, a relevância de algo simples se torna importante, tornando o tempo de execução maior.

**Consideração**: O compilador sempre irá verificar se há um `else`, não é um processo a mais, é algo inerente ao condicional `if`.

Answer (score 1):

A alternativa "A", vale muito a pena se houver uma chance maior de a mensagem ser "OI". Por exemplo, se sabe que existem mais homens que mulheres num determinado estado.

Ao fazer o cadastro, vale a pena fazer:

```
char sexo = 'M';
if (mulher)
    sexo = 'F';
```

Porém, não se preocupe com esse tipo de coisa. O processador tem uma capacidade muito grande e a diferença no tempo de execução é de milésimos. Por exemplo, um professor meu disse que:

```
int A = 10;
```

é 0,000014 mais rápido que

```
int A = 2 * 5;
```

Mas me diga, será que 0,000014 vai fazer diferença na sua aplicação? Claro que não, mas se mesmo assim você está curioso a respeito da diferença de tempo, faça o seguinte.
Declare um stopwatch, execute o método A, e então pare e exibe o tempo que decorreu.
Depois, declare outro stopwatch, execute o método B, e então exiba o tempo e ainda veja a diferença entre os dois. O Stopwatch marca o tempo passado até sua parada (como um cronômetro). Pode testar (:

**EDIT**

**EXEMPLO DE USO:**

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
//seu código aqui
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
```

Comment: Na verdade a maioria dos compiladores irá resolver 2 * 5 em tempo de compilação e apenas armazenar 10 em tempo de execução.

Comment: Pode ser que eu tenha me enganado então. Meu professor me ensinou assim.

Comment: Que meus professores me desculpem mas o Stack Overflow é o melhor professor de programação que eu tive em minha vida!

Comment: Quem sabe inglês deveria ler a série de posts sobre benchmark que o [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) escreveu em http://tech.pro/blog/1293/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-one

Answer (score 0):

Isso vai depender de caso a caso. Se `exibirAdeus` for `false` na maioria dos casos, a alternativa A é mais eficiente, principalmente se a inicialização da variável for custosa.
Senão, vai fazer muito pouca diferença, é mais questão de estilo mesmo.