# Atribuir uma expressão a uma variável

Tags: c++, variáveis

Em C++ é possível executar expressões dentro de uma variável? Ex. em Lua:

```
n = math.random(9, 10)
a = n .. (#tostring(n) > 9 and "-" or "--")
print(a)
```

Se não fosse igual a 9 retornaria:

```
9--
```

Se não, retornaria

```
10-
```

Em C++ tentei:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a = (1>2 && 5 || 10);
        std::cout << a;
return 0;
}
```

Mas retornou:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:4:20: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
  int a = (1>2 && 5 || 10)
                    ^
prog.cpp:5:3: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘std’
   std::cout << a;
   ^
prog.cpp:4:6: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
  int a = (1>2 && 5 || 10)
      ^
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como você não conhece bem os conceitos básicos você usa termos errados. A frase "Expressões dentro de uma variável" não faz sentido. O que existe é atribuir uma expressão a uma variável. Qualquer linguagem de programação de alto nível pode fazer isto, é algo básico.

## Expressão condicional

O que na verdade você está querendo saber é se é possível ter expressões condicionais para gerar o valor a ser atribuído para a variável. E sim, isto é possível. Desconheço alguma linguagem que não possa fazer isto. Desde a expressão mais simples até a que parece que você quer fazer.

Muitos programadores não entendem o funcionamento de alguns comandos das linguagens por não entenderem os conceitos básicos. Quando se tenta aprender muito na prática sem entender bem a teoria vai aprendendo tudo pela metade e sempre fica mais difícil entender o todo. Comandos como `if`, `while` e `for` esperam um valor booleano (`true` ou `false`) sempre para tomar uma decisão. Este valor pode ser obtido de forma direta através do literal ou através de uma expressão condicional, o que é mais comum. Exemplos:

```
while (true)
```

É um valor tão válido quando `while (variavel > 10)`. Ora, então podemos fazer isto:

```
bool condicao = variavel > 10;
while (condicao)
```

O que me impressiona é que é comum as pessoas criarem variáveis em excesso nos programas. E neste caso em que uma variável pode ser criada com a expressão condicional e depois usar no comando condicional "ninguém" pensa que é possível fazer. Não estou dizendo que esta forma deveria ser usada frequentemente, mas em alguma momento pode ser útil. O importante aqui é entender o que é uma expressão condicional.

Aí não faz sentido fazer:

```
bool condicao = variavel > 10;
while (condicao == true)
```

E eu vejo muitas vezes as pessoas fazerem isto. Elas acham que em um `if` ou `while` se não tiver um operador relacional está errado. E é justamente o oposto. Precisa ter um valor booleano. Se ele é gerado por uma expressão ou um valor simples, não importa. Outro exemplo:

```
if (arquivo.eof() == false)
```

Não faz sentido, seria melhor fazer:

```
if(!arquivo.eof())
```

## Operador ternário

Mas o que realmente você quer saber é se é possível criar uma expressão onde você testa uma condição e decide se vai usar um dos dois resultados seguintes. Cada linguagem tem uma estratégia para fazer isto. C++ usa um operador ternário (porque tem três operandos) condicional.

Ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 1 > 2 ? 5 : 10;
    std::cout << a;
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/a2mWap). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/upbggaov-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/ConditionalInVariable.cpp).

Perguntas que falam sobre este operador:

- [Dificuldade na Sintaxe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34200/101)
- [Diferenças entre If e operador ternário ?:](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17398/101)
- [Melhor prática para criação de if](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3839/101)
- [Como funciona este if/else com "?" e ":"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4907/101)
- [Quando usar condição ternária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3647/101)
- [O que significa ? e : dentro de uma expressão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10539/101)
- [Como simplificar o seguinte IF em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9962/101)
- [Tentando condensar condicional com três possibilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42711/101)

Comment: Perfeito. Quanto a expressão condicional, eu sou ciente disto, rs. Mas obrigado pela explicação e pela clareza.

Comment: A resposta completa é para ajudar todos. Aproveito a oportunidade para tentar incutir a conceituação correta sempre que posso.