# Porque um if pode ser redundante?

Tags: java, netbeans, if, sintaxe

Utilizando um método que retorna um `boolean` o sistema determinaria se um numero é positivo ou negativo. Então fiz desta maneira:

```
    public boolean isPositive(float num) {
    boolean positive;
    if (num >= 0) {

    positive = true;
        } else {

    positive = false;

    }return positive;
```

Então o Netbeans declarou que "a instrução if é redundante" e corrigiu para:

```
    public boolean isPositive(float num) {
    boolean positive;
    positive = num >= 0;
    return positive;
```

e funcionou.

Como não fez uso de `if` fiquei perplexo em saber q funcionou, já que não fica evidente em que situação ele retornaria um FALSE. A minha dúvida é: como? Qual a lógica da segunda declaração do método?

OBS: As duas declarações funcionam.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O `if` solicita uma condição boolean certo?

então quando você passa uma expressão (`num >= 0`), esta irá retornar um `boolean`.

Esqueça o `if`, qual é a função do seu Método?

Retornar `true` se for maior que zero, certo?

Então você passa esta informação à variável e a retorna.

Outra forma de implementar este método seria:

```
public boolean isPositive(float num) {
    return num >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Na verdade o NetBeans foi tão esperto quanto ele poderia ser. Deveria ser assim:

```
return num >= 0;
```

Ora, qual é o resultado da expressão `num >= 0`? É um booleano, certo? Ou seja, o resultado dessa "conta" será ou `false`, ou será `true`. Ou é "maior ou igual a zero", ou não é, só isto pode ocorrer.

Então por que não usar este resultado direto? Se o que você precisa é definir um `true` quando esta expressão resultar em `true` e você precisa de `false` quando a expressão resultar em `false`, então use o resultado da expressão e simplifique a lógica.

Percebo que muito programador acha que o `if` é uma coisa mágica, e que você tem uma condição lá dentro. Na verdade o `if` espera uma expressão booleana, uma expressão condicional. Pode ser um **literal**, uma **variável** simples (com valor do tipo booleano), ou uma expressão complexa cujo **resultado** seja um booleano.

Tudo isto é válido (mesmo que o primeiro não faça sentido a não ser para teste):

```
//literal
if (true)

//variável
variavel = outraVariavel > 0 && maisUmaVariavel.equals("teste");
if (variavel)

//expressão
if (outraVariavel > 0 && maisUmaVariavel.equals("teste"))
```

O `if` serve pra controle de fluxo, ele decide apenas se ele deve executar um bloco ou outro, se disponível. A decisão se dá por um valor booleano qualquer, de onde ele vem, não importa. O código deste método não precisa de um controle de fluxo, ele só precisa de de um resultado booleano.

O mesmo vale para o `while` e `for`, são apenas controles de fluxo cuja decisão se vai desviar para outra linha ou continuar na seguinte é determinada por um valor booleano que pode ser obtido por uma das três formas citadas acima.

Faça assim que estará simplificando o código e obtendo o mesmo resultado:

```
public boolean isPositive(float num) {
    return num >= 0;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/Boolean.java).

[Leitura complementar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44741/101).

Answer (score 9):

Pode-se dizer que o Netbeans é uma IDE bem chata, pois ela não deixa vc programar e faz tudo sozinha. kkkk

É o seguinte, algumas IDEs, são inteligentes e fazem o possível para reduzir o código ou consertar possíveis *bugs*. No seu caso a IDE quis eliminar a quantidade extra de código, no caso a condição, então ela salvou o resultado da condição em uma variável e retornou.

```
public boolean isPositive(float num) {
    boolean positive;
    positive = num >= 0; // (num >= 0) returna true ou false
    return positive;
}
```

como não vai ficar chamando comandos dentro das condições, não há necessidade em tê-las, e é possível reduzir mais ainda o código.

```
public boolean isPositive(float num) {
    return (num>=0); // retorna diretamente true ou false
}
```

Quanto menos código no seu sistema, mais rápido passará pelos métodos, quando o software faz muitas verificações, ele tem uma sequencia necessária para efetuar a condição, por isso é recomendado fazer de tudo para ter menos linhas de códigos escritos.

Answer (score 9):

`num >= 0;` é uma expressão que pode ser avaliada com retorno de `true` ou `false` É possível simplificar mais um pouco jogando a expressão direto no return, `return num >= 0;`