# Sintaxes de comparação se referindo a mesma variável

Tags: característica-linguagem, sintaxe, comparação

Vou dar um exemplo em C#:

```
namespace Compare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name = "Girl";
            if(name == "Girl" || == "girl") //...
        }
    }
}
```

Essa forma contém claramente um erro, não é possível fazer a comparação dessa forma, eu deveria repetir o nome da variável e ficaria assim: `if (name == "Girl" || name == "Lady")`.

- Por que as linguagens de programação não permitem fazer dessa forma
  quando queremos se referir a mesma variável?

Talvez exista um motivo, eventualmente eu cometo esse erro por achar que essa seria a forma mais lógica. Claro que quando queremos fazer a comparação, ou outras `(&&, !=)`. Incluindo outras variáveis ficaria inevitável, eu entendo isso.

Já usei JavaScript, PHP, C# e nenhuma permite esse tipo de comparação.

Comment: O motivo é bem simples, foi definido que cada comparação tem de ter 2 operandos. Isso que está a tentar fazer seria criar uma exceção à regra

Comment: Relacionada: [É uma prática ruim fazer esta comparação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240338/É-uma-prática-ruim-fazer-esta-comparação)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Está coberto de razão na contestação. Poderia existir, não com essa sintaxe que é esquisita e talvez crie ambiguidade, mas uma outra poderia.

## A matemática é assim

De fato a própria matemática tem encadeamento de operadores. Mas um humano pode *parsear* a expressão com mais contexto do que um compilador.

O encadeamento simples pode dificultar a [criação do compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101) e diminuir sua performance e até impedir a resolução de certos casos.

Na verdade o encadeamento poderia gerar erros de interpretação sobre a intenção do programador. Nada grave, nada que não aconteça em outros casos da sintaxe das linguagens, mas é algo que preferiram evitar. Provavelmente teria que ter certas restrições do que pode usar, por exemplo não poder misturar operadores.

## Exemplos do que pode ser adotado

Os casos mais interessantes seriam:

```
x > 0 && x < 10
```

que poderia ser escrito como

```
x between 0, 10
```

e também

```
x == 1 || x == 2
```

que seria simplificado para

```
x in (1, 2)
```

Os nomes poderiam ser substituídos por símbolos.

De fato existem linguagens menos populares que adotam esse tipo de sintaxe.

Eu acho o padrão de projeto ([sim, é um *design pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/96452/101)) tão comum que poderia valer a pena.

Dá para pensar em outras sintaxes, até mais genéricas. Por exemplo, poderia ter um símbolo, por exemplo `$`, onde você usa para indicar o nome da última variável usada, assim já simplificaria. Não estou dizendo que isso é bom e não tem problemas, apenas uma ideia. Muitas pessoas considerarão esquisito e menos legível, essencialmente para economizar digitação, o que é uma bobagem pra se preocupar.

Python permite fazer `0 < x < 10`. Em algumas linguagens isso seria interpretado como `(0 < x) < 10` e funcionaria, mas daria um resultado inesperado. A operação dentro dos parênteses geraria um booleano que depois seria usado para comparar com 10. Tem linguagens que podem identificar que um booleano não pode misturar com um número e adotar o comportamento de operador encadeado, mas é exceção, é complicado lidar com isto no compilador. E tem situações que o compilador se perderia. Tem situações piores, inclusive que o Python gera algo possivelmente inesperado.

Características que podem gerar *bugs* normalmente são evitadas pelas linguagens.

## Performance

Umas das vantagens do operador `in` é que ele é resolvido em compilação e não gera custo de execução, podendo até ser gerado um algoritmo diferente dependendo da quantidade de operandos ou outros fatores, ao contrário do exposto pelo Isac que dá uma solução que pode ser boa em certos cenários.

## Nem tudo são flores

Mas eu vejo um problema que pode ser o motivo das linguagens mais modernas. Não vou falar das mais antigas porque elas eram rudimentares.

Tudo que faz em uma linguagem tem consequências em outras partes. Quanto mais complica um ponto, pode estar complicando exponencialmente outras partes. A não ser que a funcionalidade seja completamente ortogonal, o que é raro, terá que pensar em soluções para outros pontos.

## Sobrecarga de operadores

Se o operador `in` é um operador como outro qualquer ele deveria ter a capacidade de ser sobrecarregado como os demais, certo? Aí a execução não poderia ser otimizada adequadamente e cairia no mesmo compromisso de usar uma função que faça isto.

Pode pensar que em linguagens que não tenha sobrecarga de operadores pode fazer sem problemas. Mas se fizer assim praticamente impede da linguagem ter a sobrecarga no futuro. Muitas funcionalidades quando colocadas na linguagem impedem outras, por isso é bom evitar certas coisas.

Claro que poderia fazer uma exceção e não ter sobrecarga para certos operadores. Isso até já existe, mas pode ficar esquisito neste caso porque a comparação simples tem sobrecarga e a múltipla não tem?

Mesmo se tiver a sobrecarga acho que otimizações normais ou específicas podem ainda fazer valer a pena usar.

O mesmo vale para o comparador de grandeza encadeado, o primeiro exemplo que eu mostrei.

## Outros problemas

Certamente em uma análise rápida não olhei para todos os problemas que pode ter nesta funcionalidade. É possível que tenham pensado em outras que eu não percebi.

Claro que eu acho que para tudo tem solução. A questão é se ela é boa o suficiente.

## Fatores psicológicos

As pessoas estão acostumadas com uma sintaxe, quando introduz uma nova há sempre alguma dificuldade das pessoas aceitarem. Qualquer linguagem que faça isso terá a pecha de ser esquisitona, mesmo que seja só uma percepção sem fundamento. Ninguém quer isso na sua linguagem.

Já há controvérsias sobre o uso de `==` que é fácil confundir com `=`.

## Notas finais

[Expressões booleanas são independentes e podem ser usadas em qualquer lugar onde se espera um valor booleano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124309/101). É comum as pessoas acharam que comparações só podem ser usadas em um `if` ou `while`.

Algumas respostas falam sobre álgebra booleana. Apesar de o assunto ter a ver com isso a questão da sintaxe do operador nada tem a ver com a álgebra em si. Não importa como é a sintaxe gerando um resultado booleano é o que importa, o fato de ter esta ou aquela sintaxe nada importa do ponto de vista booleano e não é o motivo para não ter nas linguagens. Também nada tem a ver com o código Assembly gerado. Sintaxe é algo independente.

A comparação específica de exemplo não é necessária, basta comparar com insensitividade:

```
name.Equals("girl", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

## C# 9

Agora dá para fazer algo próximo disso, talvez até melhor:

```
name is "Girl" or "girl"
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/UuWIjl) (esperando atualizarem versão). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RUxckZ). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Operator/IsOr.cs).

A outra resposta diz que isto é impossível, então C# é milagrosa.

Outra novidade que deve vir aí em futuras versões é o [operador de ternário de comparação](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4108). Não confundir com o ternário condicional que já existe. Por isso que eu sempre disse para não chamar o condicional de ternário. Assim poderá fazer igual ao Python.

Comment: Estava esperando o exemplo do Python, até que o vi em sua resposta

Comment: Bacana essa inovação do C#

Answer (score 6):

A sintaxe adotada nas comparações lógicas nas linguagens de programação evoluiu a partir da fusão de diferentes áreas de conhecimento, contudo, duas são predominantes quanto à influência que tiveram:

1) matemática: os primeiros computadores foram concebidos como máquinas para automação de cálculo aritméticos, como sabemos, a mais simples operação aritmética envolve sempre dois fatores: a + b

2) lógica: com os estudos de George Boole sobre lógica pura no século XIX foi desenvolvida uma notação específica que, embora não antevisse o advento dos computadores, inspirou as soluções técnicas para a automação de cálculos.

De modo geral a lógica de Boole (ou booleana) preconiza fundamentalmente:

a) você começa sempre com a idéia de que para uma dada afirmação sobre P somente podem haver uma de duas possibilidades, verdadeiro ou falso, nada mais.

b) a partir daí você pode formar outras afirmações, que deverão ser verdadeiras ou falsas, combinando-as entre si com o uso de operadores (and, or, xor, not)

Como você pode perceber o que inspirou a sintaxe moderna baseou-se na forma mais simples de uma comparação lógica, ou seja, entre dois fatores.

Agora você questiona porque as linguagens obrigam que se repita a variável como no exemplo dado:

```
if(name == "Girl" || == "girl")
```

A resposta é que este formato viola o princípio básico da comparação entre dois fatores e, com isso, impossível aos interpretadores e compiladores inferir que a comparação com "girl" se refere à "name".

As linguagens modernas utilizam portanto uma notação que não permite aos interpretadores e compiladores inferir o significado das comparações lógicas.

Contudo, nada impede que no futuro outras linguagens de programação seja construídas partindo de princípios diferentes dos tradicionais.

Comment: (Sobre interpretar algumas cláusulas booleanas) Com exceção do `and` para algumas coisas com Python, conforme ilustrado na resposta do Maniero

Answer (score 6):

### Por que é assim?

Esse tipo de estrutura condicional é baseada na [álgebra booleana](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lgebra_booleana). Sim ou não. Verdadeiro ou falso. Um ou zero. Funciona assim no BASIC (1964), no C (1972), no Java (1995) e nas demais linguagens que você for capaz de pensar. A estrutura mais padrão é:

```
SE condição ENTÃO faça [SE NÃO faça2] FIM SE
```

É obrigatório que `condição` seja ou se transforme em booleano. A `condição` pode ser múltipla e pode utilizar operadores como igual, maior ou igual, menor ou igual, menor, maior e por aí. Tudo completamente matemático até então.

O seu código Java, C#, C, C++, BASIC e qualquer será traduzido em código de máquina. Veja esse código Java:

```
if (x >= y) {
    // cláusula 1
} else {
    // cláusula 2
}
```

Será traduzido para algo assim (pseudo-assembly):

```
cmp (r1),(r2)    // compara os operandos nos respectivos endereços de memória apontados pelos registros r1 e r2
blt else         // pula para o else se r1 é menor que r2
   ...           // aqui o código da cláusula 1
bra end_if       // pule para o end_if
else:
   ...           // aqui o código da cláusula 2
end_if:
```

<sup>O código de máquina consiste inteiramente em dados binários, porém estruturalmente similar à código assembly. [Fonte](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187159/how-does-if-else-work-internally-in-all-programming-languages)</sup>

- [Assembly Conditions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/assembly_conditions.htm)

Talvez a forma mais direcionada, performática e ainda sim matemática que os designers das linguagens acharam para fazer operações condicionais foi no primeiro padrão que citei. E desde então fazem assim.

### Não é regra!

O resto é característica da linguagem, mas tudo gera uma estrutura condicional comum no final das contas. É pra facilitar a leitura e o desenvolvimento, na maioria das vezes. O que importa, como o Maniero disse, é gerar um resultado booleano.

**Ruby**

Veja o que é possível fazer no Ruby:

```
faça() if condição
```

Citei para mostrar que pode ser diferente. Outro exemplo em Ruby:

```
x = 1 
unless x>=2
   puts "x é menor que 2"
 else
   puts "x é maior que 2"
end
```

**Python**

O Python tem [comparações em cadeia](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), veja:

```
if (0 < x < 10):
    # ...
```

Isto é, no Python `x < y <= z` é o que mesmo que `x < y and y <= z`.

**Common Lisp**

O Common Lisp (e variantes) [tem operadores encadeados](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%25_sec_6.2.5), mas de forma mais interessante ainda, veja:

```
(< a b c d)
```

é o mesmo que

```
(a < b < c < d)
```

Essas operações em cadeia existem desde o BCPL, Basic Combined Programming Language, que influenciou a linguagem C.

**.NET**

Fiz uma [pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240338/%C3%89-uma-pr%C3%A1tica-ruim-fazer-esta-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o) focada mais em C# sobre comparativos e o método `Contains()`, quando há um emaranhado de possibilidades a serem comparadas com um único valor, por exemplo:

```
if(foo == "abc" || foo == "54" || foo == "23A" || foo == "3xe" || foo == "123") { ... }
// versus
if(new String[] {"abc", "54", "23A", "3xe", "123"}.Contains(foo)) { ... }
```

É uma implementação semelhante interessante, vale a leitura das boas respostas que tem lá se quiser mais sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 5):

> Porquê as linguagens de programação não permitem fazer dessa forma
>   quando queremos se referir a mesma variável?

O motivo principal, assim como disse em comentário é mesmo porque cada comparação tem que ter 2 operandos, um operando esquerdo e um direito.

Tem que ser algo como:

```
operando1 comparador operando2
```

Em que o comparador pode ser um de 6: `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`
Em Javascript e PHP até tem 2 comparadores extra que pode utilizar o `===` e o `!==`

Assim sendo o que está a tentar fazer é criar uma exceção à regra. Naturalmente daria para o compilador poder interpretar esse caso especial que apresentou, mas os criadores das linguagens não acharam que fosse relevante criar essa exceção, e poderia até gerar ambiguidade na leitura.

Pode pensar que dificulta bastante se tiver um caso com muitas comparações:

```
if (name == "Girl" || name == "Lady" || name == "Miss" || name == "Girly" || 
    name == "Ma'am" || name == "Madam" || name == "Misses")
```

Mas isso não é verdade, pois se tiver assim tantos casos significa que concecionou mal a sua solução e que seria melhor resolvida de outra forma:

Exemplo (Javascript):

```
const validNames = ["Girl", "Lady", "Miss", "Girly", "Ma'am", "Madam", "Misses"];

if (validNames.indexOf(name) != -1)
```

```js
const validNames = ["Girl", "Lady", "Miss", "Girly", "Ma'am", "Madam", "Misses"];

function validar(n){
  if (validNames.indexOf(n) != -1) console.log(n + " encontrado");
  else console.log(n + " não Encontrado");
}

validar("Lady");
validar("Rose");
```

Isto ira permitir lhe trocar todos os `ifs` com N comparações por um simples `indexOf` e tornar todo o código muito mais fácil de manter. Imagine o que era ter que trocar todos esses `ifs` espalhados pelo programa fora se agora tivesse mais um nome a considerar. Na solução que propus apenas tinha que adicionar um novo nome ao array num local único.

O mesmo se aplica se quiser ter uma ação diferente para cada tipo de nome. Nesse caso pode construir um mapa com os nomes e funções a executar e chamar a que interessa com base no nome.