# Evitando comparação "!=null" em Java

Tags: java, operadores, nullpointerexception

Eu trabalho com Java e por inúmeras vezes eu tenho que fazer um teste `object != null` no objeto antes de acessá-lo para evitar [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)

Entretanto, acho que essa prática acaba tornando o código muito feio, sujo e difícil de se ler.

Existe alguma alternativa para evitar essa comparação todo momento que eu desejar acessar o método de um objeto?

Por exemplo:

```
System.out.println("Nome: " + pessoa.getNome());
```

Para ficar seguro se torna:

```
if (pessoa!=null) {
    System.out.println("Nome: " + pessoa.getNome());
}
```

Comment: Interessante, tanto pergunta quanto resposta são traduções da fonte que você listou.

Comment: Sim. O que você quis dizer?

Comment: Foi só uma constatação, não vejo nada de errado. No stackoverflow em inglês, um dos requisitos é que o autor faça uma pergunta sobre um problema concreto que está encontrando, não teórico. Não sei quais são as recomendações para a versão em português, mas acho que seria mais sincero se colocasse um aviso no topo dizendo que pergunta e resposta apareceram originalmente na versão em inglês, com link para ela. Da forma que está, parece que a pergunta e resposta são originais suas, com "fonte" na versão em inglês. Fonte, neste caso, sendo "cópia" (geralmente, "fonte" é somente uma referência).

Comment: Entendo seu ponto. Também achava incorreto/estranho isso a princípio, mas tem um post no meta que cita exatamente isso: _Apoiamos a re-escrita de perguntas ou respostas do Stack Overflow, desde que elas beneficiem a sua comunidade. Tenha sempre em mente, porém, que traduções automatizadas ou mal escritas não são permitidas._ [Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com). A propósito, não simplesmente traduzi, dei meu ponto de vista nisso. Isso foi um problema real que já enfrentei no passado e aquela pergunta/resposta já me ajudaram.

Comment: Ok, também acho que esta pergunta/resposta beneficiam a comunidade, mas se fosse o autor da pergunta/resposta dos originais, teria a sensação de que é uma cópia sem atribuição apropriada da autoria, por mais que tenha um ou outro elemento original :-)

Comment: O que acharia o autor dessa pergunta ou resposta no SO.com então: [Por que processar uma lista ordenada é mais rápido que uma não ordenada?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3163/3117) ? :-)

Comment: Não tinha visto, mas faria o mesmo comentário que fiz aqui...

Comment: A propósito, no rodapé da pergunta ele colocou: "Baseado em uma pergunta famosa do SO". Isso é atribuição suficiente, imagino.

Comment: Link original: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Qual estilo de código utilizar?

Existem dois tipos de programação que podemos utilizar: por contrato ou defensiva.

- A programação por contrato é algo mais difícil de encontrar por aí. Ela prega que a pessoa deve ver o que o método espera, o que a documentação diz para usar e seguir. Problema do desenvolvedor se não seguir essas regras. Erros acontecerão mas isso não importa, ele não enviou os dados direito. Como isso afeta o código? Você não precisaria validar os atributos recebidos e simplesmente deixar o erro estourar. O problema dessa abordagem são os diversos erros de runtime que aparecerão e também a necessidade constante de uma documentação detalhada e atualizada.
- Já a programação defensiva prega que você deve validar tudo que for importante para o método chamado. Validar desde os atributos simples (`String`, `int`, etc) como objetos do seu modelo (Casa, Carro, etc). A desvantagem disso é que você sempre terá um `if` a mais em seu código para validação.

### O que posso fazer para validar?

Você pode usar diversas técnicas para validar uma atributo:

- Usar bibliotecas que diminuam o código. O ApacheCommons, por exemplo, tem diversas classes que facilitam a validação. Posso citar o `StringUtils.isBlank(texto)` para validar se o texto está vazio ou não. E o interessante é que para facilitar a leitura do código, eles criaram o método `isNotBlank(texto)` que é a negação.
- Utilizar o JSR 303: Bean Validation. É a especificação de validação dos dados. Basta anotar com um `@NotNull` e pronto. Dê uma olhada no Hibernate Validator.
- Fazer um IF na unha. Essa é uma solução bem simples, mas como já foi dito deixa o código maior. O melhor mesmo seria isolar esse código em um método a parte.
- Utilizar assert. Esse eu não recomendo e para falar a verdade, ninguém recomenda a utilização do assert em produção. Ele mata a thread que invocou o método.

### Conclusão

Para esse tipo de situação não existe uma solução perfeita, mas existe alternativas que ajudam no desenvolvimento de um código mais limpo.

Comment: Uma prova de que aqui não é o SO.com :-). No final é a comunidade que decide o que é bom para cá ou não. Mas uma coisa me intrigou, pq não recomenda asserts? Vou pesquisar sobre isso, mas é a primeira vez que vejo alguém desrecomendando.

Comment: Justamente pelo seu conceito. Não é nem aconselhável fazer um try/catch em um assert (http://www.coderanch.com/t/396087/java/java/assert-statements-catch-blocks). O conceito do assert é, deu problema e a coisa foi feia. Tanto que para ativar um assert um parâmetro na JVM é necessário -ea por exemplo. No google é fácil encontrar referências que falam que o assert não deve ser utilizado em produção. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347164/appropriate-use-of-assert

Answer (score 4):

Complementando as respostas acima, tenho mais uma sugestão.

Ela até que foge bastante do que você normalmente vê em Java, mas é muito interessante.

A API [`Google Guava`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), que é mais um desses canivetes que você tem disponíveis pra te ajudar, tem uma parte orientada ao tratamento de nulos.

Eles mesmos exemplificam na [documentação](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) mas vou deixar uns exemplos aqui pra clarificar a resposta.

Primeiro exemplo de como remover completamente `null` do seu código:

```
Optional<Integer> possible = Optional.of(5);
possible.isPresent(); // retorna true
possible.get();       // retorna 5
```

O que aconteceu aí? Você tem uma classe `Optional<T>` que pode ou não ter um valor, só que ela te obriga a tratar esse valor na hora, pois se você invocar `get()` sem um valor ali dentro, é lançada uma `IllegalStateException`, justamente para não  existir `null` em lugar nenhum.

Se quiser um valor default também é possível:

```
possible.or(0); // retorna o valor se existir, se não houver nada, retorna 0
```

A ideia é você realizar esses tratamentos longe da regra de negócio. Assim que os recebe do usuário, ou no momento em que os retorna do banco de dados, para que não se preocupe com isso nas partes mais complexas.

Se você clicar o link acima vai ver muito mais classes, exemplos e métodos utilitários.

> *"Null sucks." - [Doug Lea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Lea)*

Answer (score 3):

Esse é um problema que desenvolvedores sem muita experiência costumam enfrentar: eles ou não sabem ou não confiam no contrato que estão participando e na defensiva acabam exagerando na verificação por null's. Adicionalmente, quando escrevem o próprio código, eles possuem o hábito de retorna null's para indicar alguma coisa, e isso acaba gerando a necessidade de verificar por null's pelo método que tentou invocar o objeto.

Em resumo, exitem dois casos que pedem a verificação por null's:

**1)** Quando `null` não é uma resposta válida, em termos de contrato:

Nesse caso, use o recurso [AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) ou apenas deixe a exceção ocorrer, use as informações geradas pelo `error` ou `exception` para debugar deu código e entender por que a condição indesejada aconteceu, então conserte sua lógica para evitar essa condição. Faça todos os tipos de testes possíveis, quanto antes o erro ou a exceção ocorrer melhor, você não vai querer descobrir um bug depois que houver lançado seu programa.

`assertion` é um recurso que foi adicionado ao Java 1.4 mas que ainda não é tão praticado pelos programadores. É excelente para encontrar bugs pois você pode fazer testes para se certificar que você está tendo o resultado esperado em determinados pontos do programa.

*"- Mas eu posso fazer esses testes usando `if`s, correto?"*

Correto, entretanto com `assertions` você testa de uma forma muito mais prática pois não precisa escrever todo um código de manipulação e exibição da mensagem de erro. Além do mais o `assert` não é habilitado por padrão, logo você pode habilitá-lo enquanto debuga seu programa e quando distribui-lo os `assert`s vão normalmente desabilitados. Usando uma lógica com o `if` você deve se lembrar de apagar o código de depuração de erros antes de distribuir seu programa para não correr o risco de exibir uma mensagem para o usuário que nunca deveria ter sido exibida.

Sintaxe:

```
assert <condição>
```

ou

```
assert <condição> : <objeto>
```

Se a condição falhar um `AssertionError` é lançado. Caso um objeto tenha sido indicado no segundo parâmetro o método `toString()` do `objeto` será adicionado à informação do erro lançado pelo `AssertionError`.

Exemplo:

```
public Pessoa obterPessoa(int id) {
    Pessoa resultado = null;
    if (id > 50) {
        resultado = datasource.getPessoa(id);
    } else {
        resultado = new Pessoa(id);
    }
    assert resultado != null : "pessoa nula no método obterPessoa()";

    return resultado;
}
```

Em resumo:

> Conheça seu contrato, debug-o e confie nele.

**2)** Se `null` for uma resposta válida em termos de contrato:

Nesse caso não há muita escolha, você tem que testar o objeto antes de usá-lo.

Ou se quiser melhorar seu código você pode muda-lo e inicializar seus objetos e seus atributos, para eles nunca retornarem `null`, nem que o método do objeto retorne *vazio* isso já evita o temido `NullPointerException`.

Talvez você queira dar uma olhada no [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Exemplo:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void makeSound();
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("woof!");
    }
}

public class NullAnimal implements Animal {
    public void makeSound() {
    }
}
```

Ao invés de inicializar um objeto da class Animal como `null` inicialize-o como `NullAnimal`

Fonte(s): [Avoiding “!= null” statements in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements-in-java)