# Como verificar se a String é null ou em branco em Java / Android

Tags: java, android, string

Passei por esse problema implementando uma biblioteca simples de consultas ao banco de dados [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) em [android](/questions/tagged/android) e gostaria de compartilhar a solução com a comunidade, acredito que seja útil já que penei até encontrar uma solução simples.

> Na implementação era necessário saber se a `String` do `where` era `null` ou vazia ou se era uma `String` em branco, sendo que a verificação de `null` e vazia era simples o problema era a String em branco.

**E como fazer isso?**

Comment: vale a pena a leitura: [Evitando comparação “!=null” em Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4491/3117)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta é minha `class` utils:

```java
public class StringUtils {

    // Verifica se a String é null ou vazia ou só tem espaços em branco
    public static boolean isNullOrBlank(String s) {
        return (s == null || s.trim().equals(""));
    }

    // Verifica se a String é null ou vazia
    // Pode ser utilizado como suporte em APIs menores que 9 do android onde não está disponivel o metódo de String isEmpty()
    public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(String s) {
        return (s == null || s.equals(""));
    }
}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```java
String teste = null;
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(teste)); // true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(teste)); // true

teste = "";
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(teste)); // true
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(teste)); // true

teste = "    ";
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(teste)); // false
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(teste)); // true

teste = "  t  ";
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(teste)); // false
System.out.println(StringUtils.isNullOrBlank(teste)); // false
```

Espere que seja de grande utilidade para vocês, assim como está sendo para mim.

Fonte: http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-method-test-string-null-or-blank

Comment: Não sou especialista em Android, mas você não pode usar a **[Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)**? Acho melhor do que "reiventar" a roda. Aqui está a [**API da StringUtils**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/index.html) do commons-lang.

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Talvez sim, não conhecia esse `API`. Só "reinventei" a roda por que não conhecia essa `API`. Mas de qualquer maneira para quem não quiser importar toda uma `API` para seu projeto, compartilhei uma dificuldade que tive. Mas obrigado pela dica, me parece uma boa alternativa pronta para usar. Muito útil sua ressalva.

Comment: Concordo com você @Fernando. Não valeria mesmo a pena importar toda a commons-lang para um única validação. O bacana da API é que ela tem muita soluções para esses problemas simples que nos deparamos no dia a dia e não precisamos ficar quebrando a cabeça. Acredito que toda a [**Apache Commons**](http://commons.apache.org/) é assim.

Answer (score 3):

Mais uma API interessante para usar é a  [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). Ela tem uma série de funcionalidades para esse tipo de tarefa.

Um exemplo de uso seria:

```
 import com.google.common.base.Strings;

 Strings.isNullOrEmpty(""); // retorna true para vazia
 Strings.isNullOrEmpty("   ".trim()); // retorna true para string em branco
```

Existem diversas outras funcionalidades para primitivos, e outros conceitos como por exemplo o uso de:

**Precontitions:**

Tratamento de estado booleano de alguma condição sem guava:

```
 if (estado!= Estado.INCOMPLETO) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(
              "Esse Objeto está em um estado " + estado);
 }
```

Ficaria mais simples com Guava, sem uso de ifs:

```
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;     

  Preconditions.checkState(
    estado == Estado.PLAYABLE, "Esse Objeto está em um estado  %s", estado
  );
```

**CharMatcher:**

Determina se um caracter é um constate como:

```
  CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.matches(' ');
  CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.matches('1');
```

Ou usando um  factory method específico como:

```
  CharMatcher.is('x')
  CharMatcher.isNot('_')
  CharMatcher.oneOf("aeiou").negate()
  CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z').or(inRange('A', 'Z'))
```

Detre muitas outras funcionalidades em uma lib de apenas 2,1KB. Que inclusive teve contribuição do @Josh Block.

Mais informações:

[InfoQ Br - google-guava](http://www.infoq.com/br/news/2010/10/google-guava)

Comment: Muito boa sua contribuição, vi na sua referência que ela foi integrada com o [Google Collection](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/). +1 pela agregação.

Answer (score 3):

A partir do Java 6, a forma mais eficiente e direta para verificar se uma String não é vazia é usando o método `String.isEmpty()`. Exemplo com a verificação de `null`:

```java
if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    //é nula ou vazia
}
```

Incluindo o `trim()`:

```java
if (str == null || str.trim().isEmpty()) {
    //é nula, vazia ou só contém caracteres de espaço, tabulação e quebras de linha
}
```

A implementação do `isEmpty` apenas verifica o tamanho (`length`) do vetor de caracteres interno da classe:

```java
private final char value[];
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return value.length == 0;
}
```

Antes do Java 6 poderia ser feito assim:

```java
if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
    //é nula ou vazia
}
```

Incluindo o `trim()`:

```java
if (str == null || str.trim().length() == 0) {
    //é nula, vazia ou só contém caracteres de espaço, tabulação e quebras de linha
}
```