# Execução de Instruções

Tags: assembly, arquitetura-computadores

Estou lendo um livro sobre Introdução à Arquitetura de Computadores.

Certo trecho do livro diz os seguinte sobre a interface RISC de processadores: "cada instrução toma, tipicamente, um ciclo de clock."

Mas o mesmo livro contém o seguinte trecho ilustrativo, em linguagem Verilog:

```
always @(positiveclockedge clk )
begin
    case ( state )
        STATE_FETCH:
            begin
              fetch;
              state = STATE_DECODE;
            end
        STATE_DECODE:
            begin
                decode;
                state = STATE_EXECUTE;
            end
        STATE_EXCUTE:
            begin
                execute;
                state = STATE_FETCH;
            end
    endcase
end
```

Segundo o trecho de Verilog, mesmo processadores RISC tomam no mínimo 3 ciclos de clock para um instrução(ignorando ainda qualquer atraso no acesso à memória). Alguém pode dar-me uma luz nesse assunto, já que existe uma aparente contradição (tenho notado isso em outros textos que tenho lido)?

Comment: "cada instrução toma, tipicamente, um ciclo de clock",  presumidamente quer dizer "o estágio execute" é feito em um ciclo de clock. Penso que está certa a suposição. Fonte: Stackoverflow em inglês.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geralmente os processadores não executam uma instrução inteira em um único ciclo de clock. Mas ao mesmo tempo executam uma instrução por ciclo de clock. Como isso vem a ser possível? Pipeline!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver pelo gráfico, em média uma instrução acaba de ser executada a cada ciclo de clock, gerando a falácia de *1 instrução = 1 ciclo*.

Em cada ciclo 4 instruções podem ser executadas simultânementes. Isso, é claro, em um processador que divida o pipeline em 4 partes, pode ser uma quantidade diferente. E é por esse motivo que é tão importante que o processador possa prever qual será a proxima instrução antes mesmo de terminar a instrução atual ([Veja mais detalhes sobre *Branch Prediction*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3163/por-que-processar-uma-lista-ordenada-%C3%A9-mais-r%C3%A1pido-que-uma-n%C3%A3o-ordenada)).

Essa divisão de tarefas em partes permitem processadores mais rápidos, com tempo de clock reduzido. A dificuldade aparece em tentar se certificar que as instruções subsequentes são válidas e podem ser executadas dessa forma. Se por exemplo uma instrução escreve no registrador e a instrução seguinte lê desse mesmo registrador, temos um conflito, não dá para executar "paralelarmente" no pipeline. Alguns processadores são capazes de até mesmo reordenar as instruções para minimizar tempos de espera.

Comment: Pedagogicamente é confuso tais tipos de assertação, ainda mais para principiantes. Quando se diz "gerando a falácia 1 instrução = 1 cliclo" notoriamente se está falando de tempo, mas não de quantos ciclos foram necessários para execução da instrução. Meu grande problema foi ter que lidar com essa ambiguidade como um principiante no tema. De qualquer modo, foi muito bom o esclarecimento. "Branch Prediction" é um assunto mais avançado.

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente você tem uma arquitetura de pipeline em processadores RISC (fetch - decode - execute - write). Instruções são executadas em um único ciclo. Mas, todo o pipiline pode demorar mais ciclos, dependendo da arquitetura que se quer implementar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130325/instruction-execution/27151642