# O que são registradores e qual é o seu funcionamento básico?

Tags: assembly

Estou lendo um livro a respeito de Assembly com o objetivo de entender melhor como funciona uma linguagem de baixo nível, isso vai me ajudar a compreender de maneira mais efetiva o funcionamento interno dos programas que desenvolvo em C. E num determinado trecho, o livro menciona os registradores, veja:

> Registers are named storage locations in the CPU that hold intermediate results of operations.

Há também um exemplo de um código em C++ e Assembly, veja:

Em C++:

```
int Y;
int X = (Y + 4) * 3;
```

Em Assembly:

```
mov   eax,Y
add   eax,4
mov   ebx,3
imul  ebx
mov   X,eax
```

Na citação acima diz que eles são um local de armazenamento de dados na CPU, no entanto, eu não ainda não consigo compreender o que de fato é um registrador e qual a importância dele para o funcionamento do programa. Sendo assim, as dúvidas que surgiu são abordadas abaixo.

## Dúvidas

1. O que de fato são registradores?
2. Como é o funcionamento básico de um registrador?
3. Qual é a importância que os registradores tem em relação aos
   programas que eu desenvolvo?
4. Há alguma relação entre memória RAM e registradores?

O livro que estou lendo é *Assembly Language for x86 Processors (Sixth Edition)*.

Comment: Em outros tempos isso daria dezenas de votos, mas agora vamos torcer para 10 :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## TL; DR

> O que de fato são Registradores?

São posições de memória dentro do processador com nomes específicos, é como se fossem variáveis.

> Como é o funcionamento básico de um Registrador?

São endereços que armazenam dados por um curto período (poderia ser longo, só não faz sentido) para que o processador possa manipular esse dado ou usá-lo para manipular algum outro. Inclusive alguns servem para controle fundamental do funcionamento do processador ou da execução do seu código, em geral coisas que você nem sabe se existe.

> Qual é a importância que os Registradores tem em relação aos programas que eu desenvolvo?

Nada no sentido abstrato que você lida. Tudo concretamente. É só neles que há real execução e eles são muito mais rápidos que a memória onde você acha que seus dados estão na execução.

> Há alguma relação entre memória RAM e Registradores?

Eles são um tipo de memória de curto prazo. A única relação com a RAM é que eles se conversam o tempo todo. Em relação aos registradores dados vem e vão de e para a RAM.

## Detalhando

Basicamente é isso que está na definição :P

Memória você sabe? E [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101)?

## Memória

Memória é composta por vários *slots* de dados e podemos dizer que sempre um *slot* tem 1 byte de tamanho. O acesso a cada *slot* é feito por um número, até porque tem uma quantidade grande deles. Pensa na memória como um enorme *array* de *bytes*.

Alguns desses *slots* podem ser acessados juntos e é possível dar um nome para acessar alguns deles em específico durante a criação do código, mas de fato o acesso é feito pelo número, mesmo que você não veja isto nele.

## Registradores

Os registradores não deixam de ser uma memória, mas com características especiais e em baixíssimo número, até porque a distância que o sinal elétrico precisa percorrer precisa ser bem pequeno para acontecer muito rápido. Se tivessem muitos registradores boa parte deles ficariam longe e o tempo de acesso seria maior.

Ao contrário da memória normal, cada *slot* nessa memória dentro do núcleo do processador tem um tamanho um pouco maior, geralmente chamamos isso de [palavra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/185523/101). Então em processadores 32 bits esse tamanho é 4 bytes e um de 64 bits o tamanho é 8 bytes. Mas existem registrados especiais com tamanhos diferentes, alguns são de 1 bit porque não precisa mais que aquilo, e outros pode ter vários bytes para processar ações especiais em vetores, criptografia, etc.

Não deixa de ser um local onde *bits* ficam armazenados por um tempo, em geral bem pouco tempo, em até 1 ou poucos ciclos. Como eles são poucos podem ter um nome. Mas como tudo em Assembly não deram nomes tão fáceis. E como não é uma tarefa específica como o ocorre em um código normal de uma aplicação os nomes são bem genéricos. Mas podemos dizer que eles são as variáveis de baixo nível de qualquer código.

Mantendo a analogia que fiz com a memória entenda eles como um grande objeto com vários membros nomeados, seria definido como uma classe ou uma estrutura.

## Operações

Todas operações que o processador consegue realizar é em cima dos registradores. Não é possível manipular a memória RAM diretamente, você tem que mover a informação para o registrador manipular e depois pode mover o resultado para a RAM novamente, se for o que deseja.

As portas lógicas que executam algo pegando os bits presentes em um ou dois registradores (tem instruções especiais que podem pegar mais dados, são chamadas de [SIMD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257086/101)) e transformando em outro(s) bit(s) que devem entrar em algum(ns) registrador(es).

## Performance

O acesso a um registrador em um processador x86 tem custo na casa do picossegundos. É possível fazer 3 ou 4 bilhões de acessos por segundo. Um ARM não fica muito atrás disso. O acesso à RAM custa quase 100 nanossegundos (tem baixado um pouco), portanto uns 10 milhões de acessos por segundo. É uma diferença brutal.

Por isso é importante manter os dados no registrador. E por isso no passado escrever Assembly ajudava muito. Hoje os compiladores tendem a fazer escolhas melhores que humanos em muitos casos e coloca o que é mais importante no registrador.

Note que o tempo de acesso não é o mesmo de uma operação de manipulação. Uma divisão por exemplo pode custar vários nanossegundos até mesmo acessando apenas o registrador.

## Abstração

Tudo o que você escreve em linguagem de alto nível que toca em um dado passará por um registrador.

Esse código Assembly é um pouco alto nível porque as variáveis X e Y não existem no contexto do Assembly, aí iria endereços puros de memória (no caso da [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)).

## Limitação

Deve estar imaginando que por serem poucos registradores (16 principais nos casos mais comuns) o que fazer quando você está trabalhando com muita variáveis (mesmo que conceitualmente falando). Você vai mandando para a memória o que não cabe no processador naquele momento. Na prática isso ocorre naturalmente porque você põe alguns dados nos principais registradores, executa algo e pega o resultado mandando para a memória.

## Cache

O processador tem uma abstração legal que ele pode manter certos dados muito acessados em cache, os famosos L1, L2, L3 e finado L4 que por serem pequenos ficam mais perto do processador e tem tempos de acesso bem melhores que a RAM. E a distância é o motivo de ter vários níveis.

Em certo ponto de vista o registrador é uma espécie de cache também, onde a memória seria como o arquivo de *swap* dos sistema operacional, está lá para garantir que tudo funciona com grandes volumes, mas é melhor evitar o seu uso.

Eu poderia até falar nas novas memórias não voláteis que farão a RAM persistirem dados, ou poderia falar do *cache line* onde os dados são sempre transferidos em bloco, por isso acessar 1 byte ou 64 (tipicamente) tem custo quase igual, mas isso foge um pouco do foco.

## Registradores existentes

Existem 4 registradores principais em um processador Intel x86 que são chamados EAX, EBX, ECX, EDX. Em 64 bits os nomes são RAX, RBX, RCX, RCX e obviamente os tamanhos são maiores. Como curiosidade em 16 bits eles se chamam AX, BX, CX, DX, e eles podem ser acessados em cada byte individual na sua parte baixa ou alta, então tem o AL e AH, BL e BH, e assim por diante.

Lembre-se esses são apenas nomes como se fossem variáveis, não tem muito segredo. E podemos dizer que eles tem um tipo só, que é a palavra. Quase tudo é feito nesses registradores. O mais comum, mas só por convenção é que sejam:

- **EAX** usado como um acumulador (recebe resultados de operações)
- **EBX** seria usado como dado base para operações
- **ECX** é um contador (vai incrementando algo)
- **EDX** age como dado geral a ser usado na operação.

Outros registradores bem importantes usados o tempo todo em toda aplicação que são considerados de uso geral mas que quase sempre são usados para algo bem específico são:

- **ESP** (Stack Pointer - indicador de onde está o final da pilha na memória)
- **EBP** (Base Pointer - indicador de onde está o escopo agora, os acessos ao dado na pilha são sempre relativos a esse endereço, em geral ele indica o começo dos dados da função em execução, por isso há uma aritmética em cada acesso a um dado)
- **ESI** (Source, alguma vezes chamado de *index*)
- **EDI** (Destination, esses últimos são usados por instruções otimizadas de acesso a dados múltiplos como *arrays*, incluindo *strings*)

Lembrando que em 64 bits eles começam com R.

Depois temos registradores especiais de segmento que não há uso prático hoje em dia com o advento da memória virtual.

Um dos mais importantes registradores é o **EIP** ou **Instruction Pointer**. É ele que sabe onde do código está executando. Cada instrução que termina sua execução incrementa para o próximo endereço de execução que o código deve realizar, que é variável nos processadores Intel-like, mas tem tamanho fixo em processadores RISC como é o ARM. Um `goto` (`jmp`) entre outras instruções manipulam esse endereço desviando para um endereço específico totalmente fora da sequência.

Em 64 bits temos os **R8** ao **R15** que são registradores complementares e funcionam como os primeiros, mas sem nada mais convencional para uso e são usados como otimizações, em operações simples costumam ficar vazios (conceitualmente já que sempre terá dado que estava lá).

Não falei de registradores especiais usados por instruções MMX, SSEx, etc. porque não os entendo bem e acho que não é caso da maioria dos usos.

Finalmente chegamos nos registradores de bit (*flags*) que recebem certos resultados de controle e são consultados em certas instruções para decidir o que fazer. Já deve imaginar que role em muitas instruções de comparação, mas não só, até em aritmética pode rolar bastante. Esses registradores são atualizados em boa parte das operações, portanto você só tem o último estado, se precisa dessa informação para alguma operação posterior (geralmente não precisa) então deve armazenar em algum lugar, seja um registrador geral ou na memória. Não vou listar todos, mas os principais são (endereços dos bits):

- 00 **CF** - Carry Flag - é o famoso "vai um" (sim, o computador precisa fazer conta do jeito que você sempre fez desde criança)
- 02 **PF** - Parity Flag - indica se o resultado é par ou ímpar, o que permite algumas otimizações
- 04 **AF** - Adjust Flag - usado para cálculo [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), pouco importante hoje em dia
- 06 **ZF** - Zero Flag - controle se a operação resultou em 0 (falso)
- 07 **SF**  - Sign Flag - indica se a operação tem um sinal negativo ou não
- 08 **TF** - Trap Flag - controle de passo do *debugger*
- 09 **IF** - Interruption Flag - indica se interrupções são permitidas (responder eventos)
- 10 **DF** - Direction Flag - controle de direção de *strings*
- 11 **OF** - Overflow Flag - indica que houve estouro em operação (o resultado não cabe no espaço reservado)
- 12-13 **IOPL** - I/O Privilege Level field - indica o nível de privilégio que a operação pode realizar, algumas só o *kernel*  do SO pode realizar
- 14 - **NT** - Nested Task flag - controle de encadeamento de interrupções
- 16 - **RF** - Resume Flag - controle do *debugger*
- 17 - **VM** - Virtual-8086 Mode - estabelece modo de compatibilidade
- 18-31 - indicadores modernos de virtualização e identificação
- 1, 3, 5, 32-63 - reservados

## Seu código:

- `mov   eax,Y` - Está movendo para o registrador chamado EAX o valor que está na memória em certo endereço que é conceitualmente indicado por Y
- `add   eax,4` - Está fazendo uma operação de adição entre o valor que está em EAX e a constante 4, obviamente que o resultado alterará alguns registradores de bits e manterá o resultado em EAX mesmo, portanto é uma operação com efeito colateral ao que está sendo usado no cálculo
- `mov   ebx,3` - Está armazenando o número 3 no registrador EBX, é como se fizesse um `ebx = 3;`
- `imul  ebx` - Está realizando uma multiplicação de inteiros, que é mais simples que um de ponto flutuante usando o EBX com multiplicador, o multiplicando é implicitamente o EAX, e o resultado será armazenado em EAX, como de costume
- `mov   X,eax` - Está movendo para o que se chama conceitualmente X (na prática é um endereço de memória) o que está armazenado em EAX nesse momento.

Tipicamente isso pode demorar uns cento e tantos nanossegundos para executar. E apenas pouco mais de 2 ou 3 nanossegundo é o cálculo em si. Por isso que eu falo que **otimizar é não acessar memória**, não é economizar processamento em si. Fazer tudo o que precisa estar no processador e operar nele e conseguir evitar que registradores sejam usados de forma sobreposta em uma linha de processamento fazem absurdamente mais pela performance que economizar instruções de processamento ou usar instruções com menos ciclos de custo.

Porque toda vez que precisa usar o EAX por exemplo, e ele está ocupado, você tem que jogar para a memória o que tem ali (empilhar) para poder usá-lo sem problemas e depois que terminar essa nova operação tem que voltar o valor salvo antes na pilha para o registrador para ele continuar o que estava fazendo. Mesmo que o empilhamento ocorra no cache L1 custa bem mais caro não só porque é uma operação extra só de controle, mas também porque ela custa caro.

Um dos motivos que tenta-se fazer *inline* de funçãoé porque há muita cópia de dados do registrador para memória e vice-versa em chamadas de função.

Ao contrário do que as pessoas pensam, Assembly não é tão difícil assim, é chato, é esquisito, tem que ter muito cuidado, mas tem baixa complexidade e pouca abstração que dificulta o entendimento. Na verdade se adotassem uma sintaxe um pouco melhor assustaria menos. Mas claro, assim como em C o acesso ao *heap* ou uso de ponteiros já assusta porque é fácil cometer erros e melar a memória, em Assembly qualquer acesso assusta geral.

Pode interessar:

- [Como um computador entende o código binário?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142289/101)
- [Todo processador utiliza o mesmo conjunto de instruções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109886/101)
- [Como um programa é carregado na memória e depois executado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209542/101)
- [Execução de Instruções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41751/101)
- [Onde ficam armazenadas as instruções de um processador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/94311/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Deu para entender sim, porém, conforme a gente vai perguntando e conseguindo respostas, mais dúvidas vão surgindo, claro que futuramente irei fazer perguntas mais especificas em relação a essas dúvidas, linkando com esta pergunta. E a resposta me mostrou um caminho e como posso continuar estudando e esclareceu o "mistério" dos registradores, que de misterioso não tem nada ;)

Answer (score 11):

## O que são registradores?

São pedaços de circuitos lógicos de fim específico capazes de armazenar valores para serem trabalhados em seguida.

Você pode ter registradores inteiros, de pontos flutuantes, com 16, 32, 64 bits (outras bitagens são aceitas), etc.

Eles são nomeados para serem facilmente resgatados no código de máquina. Por exemplo, no assembly `add eax, 4` se refere a um comando (`add`) sendo aplicado sobre um registradores (`eax`) e guardando o resultado lá mesmo. Você poderia muito bem ter feito `add ebx, 4`, que é quase a mesma instrução assembly, mas iria ser outro comando para o processador de qualquer sorte.

## Como é o funcionamento básico de um registrador?

Uma CPU digna tem pelo menos duas partes: a unidade lógica aritmética (ULA), para fazer computações com números inteiros; e a unidade controladora (UC), que simplesmente é a responsável de ficar movendo as informações de um registrador para o outro, ou pegando da memória, ou devolvendo para a memória; também é a UC que é responsável para deixar tudo pronto para a ULA computar. E é a UC que fica apontando quais os registradores a serem computados.

No básico do básico, registradores funcionam como um circuito elétrico que preserva seu próprio estado (cada bit é um estado) até que cheguem dois sinais externos e ele precise mudar de sinal. O primeiro sinal externo realmente é o próximo valor desejado que se ocupe para cada bit. Mas só isso não é o suficiente: também é necessário um sinal extra para dizer "faça a troca".

### Tá, mas qual o uso prático disso?

Bem, com isso você consegue fazer computações. Uma ULA é apenas um circuito lógico que pode ser substituído com uma caixa preta, como se fosse uma porta lógica com 3 entradas e uma saída principal:

- (entrada) operando esquerdo
- (entrada) operando direito
- (entrada) código da operação
- (saída) resultado da operação

Para a ULA, não importa de jeito algum a origem dos inputs: ela simplesmente os interpretará como sinais elétricos e, sobre isso, oferecerá o resultado.

Então a função do registrador é, basicamente, ser um repositório de informações ao qual a UC ligará nas entradas e saídas da ULA a fim de fazer uma computação e guardar seu resultado.

Além dessa função primordial, registradores também guardam ponteiros de região de memória que podem ser acessadas. Nesse caso, o registrador será resgatado pela própria UC para fazer acesso a alguma região de memória. Você não botou exemplo desse uso.

## Qual a importância que os registradores tem em relação aos programas que eu desenvolvo?

Sinceramente? Difícil responder essa pergunta sem saber *quais* programas são esses. Normalmente você não vai se preocupar com isso ao se usar uma linguagem de quinta geração, devido ao seu distanciamento da CPU. Mas alguns conceitos podem fazer uma diferença tremenda: localidade temporal (nesse caso, não a espacial).

> O que é localidade? Alguns autores discorrem sobre o tema:
>
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/268362/64969
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/94335/64969
> - https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/258445/64969
>
> Em resumo, é a possibilidade de reúso de dados *cached*.

Quando você desenha seu programa de modo que facilita o compilador a alocar otimamente cada variável no registrador perfeito, você só teria gastos com operações de controle para pegar os valores da memória de trabalho e por nos registradores e vice-versa. Porém, caso você não tenha facilitado a vida do compilador, você pode forçá-lo a, sempre, a cada operação realizada, pegar os valores da memória, por nos registradores, voltar o resultado para a memória e pegar os próximos operandos.

Como se a sua multiplicação saísse de:

```
mov   eax,Y
add   eax,4
mov   ebx,3
imul  ebx
mov   X,eax
```

Para algo assim:

```
mov   eax,Y
add   eax,4
mov   Y,eax
mov   ebx,3
mov   eax,Y
imul  ebx
mov   X,eax
```

Notou que foi forçado aqui mover o resultado da soma para a memória (`mov Y,eax`)? E notou que depois precisei pegar o valor que estava em memória e deixá-lo pronto para o uso na multiplicação (`mov eax,Y`)? Na versão original isso não foi necessário fazer pois o operando já estava "no lugar" para aquele momento de tempo. Isso pode afetar profundamente o desempenho do seu programa.

> Mesmo assim, a localidade temporal faria efeito a nível de *cache L3*.
>
> Normalmente eu utilizo muito mais a localidade espacial do que a temporal, isso que afeta mais a minha vida.

Tem outro aspecto controverso também: registrador não é o único paradigma de se fazer operações assembly. Também tem a máquina de pilha (não o autômato de pilha, não confunda) que não usa registradores para nada. A JVM, por exemplo, é uma máquina de pilha, já o antigo Dalvik é uma máquina de registradores. Existem estudos a cerca do desempenho de máquinas de pilha *versus* máquinas de registradores, mas não lembro se chegaram a algum consenso ou se ainda é debatido.

## Há alguma relação entre memória RAM e registradores?

Sim. Os dados ficam na RAM, devido ao seu tamanho e alcance. É como se ela fosse a fita da máquina de Turing. Já os registradores contém apenas as informações que vão ser operadas quase que instantaneamente. Como se fossem as coisas lidas pelas cabeças da máquina de Turing.

Como na máquina de Turing, você é incapaz de operar nas coisas que estão fora das cabeças, portanto não é capaz de operar na RAM. Em compensação, você pode transportar a cabeça para os locais adequados e ler essa informação (transfere da RAM para o registrador), ou escrever na fita a nova informação (transfere do registrador para a RAM).

Comment: As 3 entradas que vão para ULA seriam `4` (operando esquerdo), `1` (operando direito), `231` (código de operação correspondente a operação de adição `+`),  `5` (resultado da operação). Os 3 dados de entrada vem dos registradores (que anteriormente estavam alocados na RAM) e quanto os dados são computados ele retornam para algum registrador para em seguida retornar para a memória RAM. Esta linha de raciocínio esta correta?

Comment: A ULA não vai se importar nem com a origem nem com o destino dos dados. Isso é preocupação de UC. Ela vai "ligar os fios" com o que se necessita. E a operação vem da instrução sendo processada, que a UC vai traduzir para a ULA de maneira adequada

Answer (score 5):

A CPU (processador) e a memória principal (RAM), partes integrantes de um computador, são componentes construídos em geral de maneira separada e não ficam tão próximos quanto seria o ideal.

Pode não parecer mas qualquer mínimo afastamento causa considerável lentidão na transferência de dados de um para o outro (quando comparado à rapidez com que ela ocorreria se estivessem bem próximos).

Essa lentidão pode causar inanição ou *starvation*, quando a CPU é capaz de processar dados mas fica ociosa por estes demorarem demais para chegar.

Outra razão para a inanição, em computadores baseados no [modelo de von Neumann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189180/357), é o [gargalo de von Neumann](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/563720/357).

A consequência disso é que vale a pena manter algumas "palavras" de memória (no sentido de conjuntos de bits) dentro do processador para acesso mais rápido.

Exceto por isso, não há nada de especial em um registrador. É uma porção de memória composta pelo mesmo tipo de componentes de circuito que poderiam compor um registrador que guarda um determinado conjunto de bits na memória RAM (tipicamente oito bits ou um byte).

**Obs.:** atualmente na prática existe uma diferenciação, com registradores sendo baseados em *flip-flops* e células de memória RAM sendo baseadas em capacitores que têm seu conteúdo periodicamente "refrescado". Registradores e memória *cache* são chamados de memória estática e RAM de memória dinâmica. Essa diferenciação existe porque memória baseada em capacitores ocupa menos área de chip e é mais barata para se produzir quando não há necessidade de se priorizar o desempenho em detrimento do custo como seria o caso dos registradores e memória *cache*, que são mais rápidos, mais caros e ocupam um número pequeno de bytes em comparação com os pentes de memória RAM atuais.

Conforme dito anteriormente o registrador faz parte da CPU e pode ser acessado muito mais rápido que os registradores que compõem a memória RAM.

Sua essência ou "miolo" é um conjunto de *latches* (travas), ou de *flip-flops*, um para cada bit que se deseja armazenar. Nesses tipos de circuitos existe um par de entradas e de saídas e ocorre a retroalimentação de uma saída na entrada oposta e vice-versa, o que é a grande sacada que permite a persistência estável da informação de bit ativado ou inativado (sob certas condições; por exemplo, é útil um sinal de *clock* estar presente no circuito a fim de sincronizá-lo).

Associados a esse circuito costumam existir um bit de entrada frequentemente chamado de *"set"* ("atribuir"), que é usado para sinalizar que se deve gravar um novo estado de bits vindo de algum lugar do barramento (*bus*), e um bit de entrada frequentemente chamado de *"enable"* ("habilitar"), que quando ativado faz o registrador expor o seu valor atual no barramento.

Isso compõe os registradores, desconsiderando os bits de controle que são usados para acessá-los, ou seja, o endereçamento desses registradores. Creio que uma explicação bem simplificada de como funciona esse endereçamento é que é tudo uma porção de portas lógicas *AND*, cujas entradas, se baterem com o endereço (bits ordenados) que vêm dos bits de controle, e produzirem a saída adequada, fazem funcionar o bit *"set"* ou *"enable"* apropriado que faz o registrador interagir com o barramento (receber ou expor dados).

Em relação à utilidade para a programação, os registradores são utilizados internamente pela CPU e quase nunca é necessário trabalhar diretamente com eles. Registradores servem para guardar dados e endereços (sejam de memória ou dos próprios registradores internos), atuam como entradas e saídas para as operações da CPU (são intermediários necessários para acessar a RAM em arquiteturas do tipo *load/store*, por exemplo), e alguns são de propósito geral enquanto outros são de propósito específico (por exemplo, geralmente um deles guarda a posição da próxima instrução a ser executada pelo processador).

Arriscando responder a pergunta 3, registradores são importantes para a programação quando você identifica e tira proveito de operações que são mais rápidas por os estarem acessando, evitando transferência de dados de ou para a memória. E que eventualmente pode-se otimizar certas partes do código programando diretamente em *assembly* e acessando os registradores internos da CPU.

Answer (score 4):

1. Os registradores são um "espaço" dentro do (micro)processador onde é possível armazenar determinados valores. Estes podem ser um valor arbitrário, o resultado de uma operação lógica/aritmética, *flags* de status ou endereços de memória para a próxima instrução a executar ou a posição da pilha de registradores (*stack*) na memória RAM.

   - Tenha em mente que os processadores não manipulam diretamente a memória (geralmente eles só recuperam ou armazenam valores), todo o resto precisa ser feito dentro deles.
2. Do ponto de vista do *assembly* eles funcionam como as variáveis, onde você faz um `a = 10` em uma linguagem você faz `LD A,10` (ou `MOV A,10`) para armazenar um valor. A diferença é que uma linguagem de programação te permite criar quantas variáveis com qual tipo e tamanho desejar enquanto que a quantidade e tamanho dos registradores é definida durante o projeto do processador (aliás, chamamos de `a`, `a'`, `eax`, `r0`, etc mas são convenções).
3. As linguagens de programação abstraem os registradores e geralmente não fazem atribuições diretas (o exemplo que você mostrou é uma tradução, a versão compilada não se parece em nada com isso), tipo de tamanho dos registradores e a não ser que você vá programar diretamente em *assembly* não fará muita diferença.
4. Não, os registradores são parte do processador (fisicamente falando) enquanto que a memória RAM é um componente externo. Por este motivo acessar o valor de um registrador é absurdamente mais rápido do que acessar o mesmo valor armazenado em RAM.

Há uma apresentação de 2011 do *Chaos Communication Congress*, sobre [engenharia reversa no MOS6502](https://events.ccc.de/congress/2010/Fahrplan/events/4159.en.html), que talvez ajude. Lá você poderá "ver" o registrador... :-)

Answer (score 2):

Registradores são um tipo de memória, o tipo de memória mais rápido à disposição da CPU.

Além da velocidade, os registradores são parte integrante da arquitetura da CPU: o número e tamanho deles são fixos, faz parte da arquitetura especificar que instruções podem usar quais registradores e para quê, etc.

Pode haver CPU sem registradores? Sim: existem ou existiram CPUs baseados em pilha, bem como CPUs cujos "registradores" são simplesmente posições fixas da memória RAM. Mas, no momento atual da tecnologia, uma hierarquia de memórias (registradores, caches L1/L2/..., memória RAM, armazenamento de massa) é o que mais bem funciona.

Comment: Minha única ressalva para o +1 é que consultei https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine e lá diz que o número de registradores é significativamente reduzido, porém não eliminado, como sugere a resposta.

Comment: Nada impede que haja uma stack machine "pura", O próprio artigo discute a possibilidade na seção "Hybrid machines" Só não é eficiente.